# Macbook pro, boot camp, can't enable wifi adapter

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, bootcamp, windows

I installed Windows 8 on my macbook pro (Item No : 8899069, Mftr Part No : MD313LL/A) via boot camp. I installed the boot camp support tools. The wifi adapter says that it is working correctly. However, when I go into the control panel, the wifi adapter is not enabled. When I try to enable it, it says "enabling...", but then goes away. It's not enabled afterwards.

I tried to uninstall the driver, and then repair the support tools. No luck.

I [followed these directions](http://photoboothowners.com/windows-8-a-macbook-pro-and-boot-camp), with no luck. I also tried to run setup.exe from these drivers, with no luck. Last, I tried to run setup.exe in compatibility mode, with no luck.

Has anyone been able to get the macbook wifi enabled in Windows 8? It reminds me of a time when I couldn't get my wifi card to work, and then I realized I didn't press the 'enable wifi' button on my pc.

I don't even see an error in the event viewer :(

Has anyone been able to get wifi to work in windows 8?

EDIT: The network card is a Broadcom 802.11n network adapter (as per the device manager)

Comment: Side question: Why does the boot camp select drive menu also have a drop down for wireless networks?

Comment: The answer to the side question is that you can reinstall OSX via wifi from the boot menu, and this is an interface to connect to secured wireless connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought an Edimax wireless card to see if it resolved the problem, but I had similar issues.

As per Edimax support:

1. Please uninstall ZoneAlarm
2. Reboot your computer
3. Then you can enable the wireless network connection
4. After the wireless is working properly, you can re-install ZoneAlarm back.

I've tested steps 1-3, and now both the built in wifi and the edimax card work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the Windows 8.1 driver from this website: [Link](http://www.necacom.net/index.php/broadcom/7845-broadcom-bcm-43xx-wireless-lan-drivers-version-6-32-223-1) (or here you have the Download Link directly: [download](http://www.mediafire.com/download/bzhpa5pawh2wh3x/Broadcom_Wlan_6.32.223.1_necacom.net.exe)).

One solution would be:

> 1. Boot into OS X
> 2. Select Windows as primary boot partition
> 3. Restart your Mac (it should boot now directly into Windows)
> 4. Restart Windows (NOT turning off. Start > Restart)

Second suggestion:

> 1. Uninstall the driver completely
> 2. Restart into OS X
> 3. Then restart into Windows

Sometimes the WiFi driver is working after a few minutes. If not: Install the driver from above (from the Download link).

It has something to do with Bootcamp and Mac. This isn't a Windows problem. The driver isn't loading properly. Maybe Apple is going to fix this.

Comment: I didn't have luck with this unfortunately. The drivers you linked to wouldn't install successfully. And the device is still disabled after following these steps.